# How to get aggregate monthly data and calculate new fields?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, alias

1. I am attempting to calculate two new fields, Sales and Quantity and also Margin calculated off of Sales and Quantity.
2. I have a yearly range and would like the sums of Sales,Quantity and Margin by Month.
3. I would like the list by individual b.ID

I've attempted to group by month but there are same months in two years.
The aliasing gives me errors

```
select distinct b.ID
 sum(a.DOLSOLD-a.DOLRETN) as Sales
 --sum(a.QTYSOLD-a.QTYRETN) as Quantity
 --Margin = Sales - Quantity * (a.UCOST)
 from History a inner join productlist b on a.PARTNUM = b.UID
 where INVDATE BETWEEN '7/1/2018' AND '6/30/2019' AND (BLINE NOT LIKE 'AVA-%' AND BLINE NOT LIKE 'ACA-%') AND BUYLINE <> 'MISC.CHG' AND BILLTOID NOT IN (2, 27029,28972)
 GROUP BY MONTH(a.INVDATE)
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 79
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.[image]

Comment: missing `,` between `b.ID` and `sum(a.DOLSOLD-a.DOLRETN)`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want something like this:

```
select year(h.invdate), month(h.INVDATE), pl.ID,
       sum(h.DOLSOLD - h.DOLRETN) as Sales,
       sum(h.QTYSOLD - h.QTYRETN) as Quantity
from History h inner join
     productlist pl
     on h.PARTNUM = pl.UID
where h.INVDATE between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-30' and
      BLINE not lik 'AVA-%' and
      BLINE not like 'ACA-%' and
      BUYLINE <> 'MISC.CHG' and
      BILLTOID not in (2, 27029, 28972)
group by year(h.invdate), month(h.INVDATE), pl.ID
order by min(h.invdate);
```

Notes:

- Use meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters like `a` and `b.  Abbreviations are easier to follow.
- Use standard date formats -- YYYY-MM-DD.
- Include the year in the `GROUP BY`.  This is a best practice even if your months are for less than one year.
- You need `pl.id` in the `GROUP BY`.
- The `ORDER BY` will order the results chronologically.

Comment: Thank you. What about calculated Revenue based off of the newly created Sales and Quantity but Quanity multiplied by a.Cost ?   Revenue = Sales- Quantity * (a.UCOST)

Comment: ``select year(h.invdate), month(h.INVDATE), pl.ID, h.UCOST,
       sum(h.DOLSOLD - h.DOLRETN) as Sales,
       sum(h.QTYSOLD - h.QTYRETN) as Quantity
    --Sales - Quantity as Revenue
from History h inner join
     productlist pl
     on h.PARTNUM = pl.UID
where h.INVDATE between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-30' and
      BLINE not like 'AVA-%' and
      BLINE not like 'ACA-%' and
      BUYLINE <> 'MISC.CHG' and
      BILLTOID not in (2, 27029, 28972)
group by year(h.invdate), month(h.INVDATE), pl.ID,h.UCOST
order by min(h.invdate);``

Comment: @actuario99 . . . You should be able to follow this example to do the calculation.  Your question has something called `margin`, but the calculation doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

no need distinct try like below

```
select  b.ID,MONTH(a.INVDATE),
 sum(a.DOLSOLD-a.DOLRETN) as Sales
 --sum(a.QTYSOLD-a.QTYRETN) as Quantity
 --Margin = Sales - Quantity * (a.UCOST)
 from History a inner join productlist b on a.PARTNUM = b.UID
 where INVDATE BETWEEN '7/1/2018' AND '6/30/2019' AND (BLINE NOT LIKE 'AVA-%' AND BLINE NOT LIKE 'ACA-%') AND BUYLINE <> 'MISC.CHG' AND BILLTOID NOT IN (2, 27029,28972)
 GROUP BY MONTH(a.INVDATE),b.ID
```